# Updating a TFS repo with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I want to checkout a TFS repo, make some changes to a file and send the changeset to TFS.

What are some ways to accomplish this with Jenkins?

Comment: tfvc or git repo?

Comment: tfvc. We have solved this posting the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using team-explorer-everywhere. We made a container that clones the code using it edits it an sends it back up. https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere

Comment: Good for you. I trust you saw the repo is is labeled **”This project is no longer maintained"**. Sad that MS appears to have abandoned TFVC. See [my remarks @D/O](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/12653/13379).